# 11ty Pagination Returns number in file structure - how do I prevent this from happening?

Tags: permalinks, eleventy, jamstack

I'm trying to create a page per item of data from my CMS in 11ty. The data has pulled through nicely, and each page outputs nicely. However, when created a permalink I'm getting:

`public/page-title/1/index.html`

Where /1/ is the iteration of the creation of the page. I've never come across this with 11ty before - does anyone know why this happens and how I can prevent it? The docs weren't particularly helpful - saying it would happen but not why or any work arounds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remap the permalinks for pagination, you can set the `permalink` front matter variable, which supports template strings ([11ty docs](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/#remapping-with-permalinks)).

You can change the permalink to be whatever you want, as well as access the paginated object ([made simple with an alias](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/#aliasing-to-a-different-variable)). For example, if you have a `slug` property on your aliased object, you might want something like this:

```yaml
---
pagination:
  data: cmsdata
  size: 1
  alias: item 
permalink: "public/page-title/{{ item.slug }}/index.html"
---
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm doing - but I am getting back public/page-title/8/index.html

where 8 is the iteration of the data - for example I have a page for each item with number 1-8, and for the first iteration, no extra folder at all.

Comment: Having worked on this today, it seems the problem is coming from using EleventyComputed.

Answer (score 1):

Through further research it turned out the problem was through using permalinks in eleventyComputed - there is a workaround as detailed in this thread:

https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/1555

TL;DR: set permalink to : "/" before setting your permalink to the path you want in eleventyComputed